# Lumen eloquent column alias change

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I am Rest API's in the lumen and Eloquent ORM.

My table column name:

```
USER_ID
FIRST_NAME
LAST_NAME
INACTIVE
CREATED_AT
UPDATED_AT
```

And I make user model get all user record using Eloquest model.

```
$res=User::where('INACTIVE','=',0)->get();
```

This working perfect.

Now my question is all column name need in camelCase so how I can do this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35390493/6309457

Comment: This not working in lumen-5.8